# VS2017 Could not load file or assembly

Tags: build, visual-studio-2017, package, badimageformatexception

I have gone over every example I can and I can't seem to get this error to go away.

I have tried =

- Setting build from x64  to x86 to AnyCPU = no work
- I have tried deleting IIS Express folder = no work
- I have tried deleting .vs project folder = no work
- I have tried changing project config from override application root URL on/off = both no work
- I have tried swapping from IIS Express in config to Local IIS = no work
- I have tried changing IIS app pool to allow 32 bit = no work

I have only noticed one thing that I have no idea if is the issue: 
picking the one assembly and checking its Version against the packages.congig file = they have different versions : could that be the issue?

What else can I do here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, tried one more thing and it worked = I had NuGet get the latest of the one library it was always erroring out on, and then the build worked again...  I think my packages and build library got out of sync somehow.  It works now though.